# Leer columnas variables en excel

Tags: python, excel

buen día. Debo leer un archivo de excel con python, en especifico una columna (Columna C), que va desde la fila C2 hasta (n) filas, ya que es variable, en estos momentos yo la tengo de esta forma, pero no quiero que esté fija

```
hoja = doc.active #variable hoja es igual a la unica hoja activa del libro
celdas = hoja['C2':'C46']
lista_auditores = []
```

por el momento va hasta la C46, sin embargo cada vez se van agregando más datos y debo ir corrigiendo y cambiando constantemente, quiero evitar estar cambiando el código y modificandolo.

Existe alguna forma? De antemano, gracias.

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de tu excel??

Comment: No sé como hacerlo, sin embargo es info que no puedo compartir. Pero te explico como es el archivo. Por el momento consta de 3 columnas (A,B, C) y de 46 filas. Las columnas se mantienen fijas, pero las filas cambian, se modifican cada semana. El archivo lee unicamente la columna C. Por esto mi pregunta, no sé si exista algun formato que permita leer desde la fila C2 hasta C(n_filas).

Comment: la primera fila contiene el nombre de la columna??

Comment: correcto @Christian, por eso ignoro esa fila.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que las columnas tiene nombre y están en la primera fila podemos usar pandas para leerlo y la ventaja de esto es que podemos escoger la columna sin importar la ubicación.

**instalacion**

```
pip install pandas
```

**uso**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("ruta_archivo.xlsx")
datos = df["nombre_columna"]
```

Pandas es utilizado para el manejo de datos y trae varias funciones que de seguro te serán mas útiles y son más simplificadas y fáciles de usar